Do these sentences (1 and 2) have the same meaning?

You don't follow my mails, that's why you missed the meeting.
Were you following my mails, you would not have missed the meeting.

I believe that they do, but my friend tells me that the second one is incorrect.

Neither of these is idiomatic. A native speaker is more likely to say "read my emails" rather than "follow my mails". The "were you" structure in 2 sounds old fashioned, so it's even more unidiomatic. Depending on your office culture, they could also come off as rude.

Using the subjunctive like that, with the verb coming first, is grammatically correct but sounds very formal and old-fashioned. It would be more natural to say "If you were..."

I suppose that they do communicate the same ideas.  We understand three opinions of person A

Person B does not follow the mails of Person A.
Person B missed the meeting
(2) is a result of (1)

Statement 2 is a "garden path" sentence, since the initial phrase is more easily understood as a question "Were you following my mails or not?"  But then when we reach the second part we are forced to backtrack and understand the first part as a condition.  That is a fault in the writing.  You could fix it with "If":  "If you were following my mails...."
Note that "follow my mails" is not an idiomatic expression, and appears to be "translationese"
